# Upload file action method in asp.net core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-web-api, file-upload, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working on a web api project and I want to upload file to sever.
I am using the below code for upload action method.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task Post([FromForm]IFormFile file)
{
    var uploads = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "uploads");
    if (file.Length > 0)
    {
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploads, 
                                          file.FileName), FileMode.Create))
       {
           await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
       }
    }
 }
```

and I am using below code for a console client for upload file to server using api.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     FileStream stream = new FileStream("D://Infos.txt", FileMode.Open);
     HttpContent fileStreamContent = new StreamContent(stream);
     fileStreamContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new 
     System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data") 
              { Name = "D://Infos.txt", FileName = "D://Infos.txt" };

     fileStreamContent.Headers.ContentType = new 
     System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/form-data");

     using (var client = new HttpClient())
     {
         using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
         {
             formData.Add(fileStreamContent);

             var response = 
             client.PostAsync("http://localhost:2184/api/values", formData);

             Console.WriteLine(response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode);
             Console.ReadKey();
          }
     }  
 }
```

But when I am running this code I receive null as file in the action method side.

I used [FromBody] attribute for IFormFile parameter of action method but it didn't work too.

Why it isn't work?

Comment: can I see your razor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following line:

```
System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data") 
              { Name = "D://Infos.txt", FileName = "D://Infos.txt" };
```

to:

```
System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data") 
                  { Name = "file", FileName = "D://Infos.txt" };
```

The model binding will not be done correctly if the names do not match.